# How do I avoid the need for MSDTC with SDL Web 8 and Translation Manager?

Tags: web8, translation-manager, sql-server

My understanding is that with SDL Web 8, the need for MSDTC was removed (assuming you do not have any of the following http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v1/GUID-34B24945-6280-4533-AC9E-A4C81DB27726)

I have installed the Translation Manager module, via the CMS installer, and specified the TM database (separate database created via "Install Translation Manager database" script)

However, when I send items for translation, I get an error consistent with the requirement for MSDTC configuration

> Translation Job id: 2 Translation Job title: Copy of Test Translation
>   Component Source Publication URI: tcm:0-4-1 Source Publication title:
>   020 Content Master (-)(EN-US)
>
> The partner transaction manager has disabled its support for
>   remote/network transactions. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8004D025)
>
> at
>   System.Transactions.Oletx.OletxTransactionManager.ProxyException(COMException
>   comException)    at
>   System.Transactions.TransactionInterop.GetOletxTransactionFromTransmitterPropigationToken(Byte[]
>   propagationToken)    at
>   System.Transactions.TransactionStatePSPEOperation.PSPEPromote(InternalTransaction
>   tx)    at
>   System.Transactions.TransactionStateDelegatedBase.EnterState(InternalTransaction
>   tx)    at
>   System.Transactions.EnlistableStates.Promote(InternalTransaction tx)
>   at System.Transactions.Transaction.Promote()    at
>   System.Transactions.TransactionInterop.ConvertToOletxTransaction(Transaction
>   transaction)    at
>   System.Transactions.TransactionInterop.GetExportCookie(Transaction
>   transaction, Byte[] whereabouts)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.GetTransactionCookie(Transaction
>   transaction, Byte[] whereAbouts)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.EnlistNonNull(Transaction
>   tx)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.Enlist(Transaction tx)
>   at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.ActivateConnection(Transaction
>   transaction)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.PrepareConnection(DbConnection
>   owningObject, DbConnectionInternal obj, Transaction transaction)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean
>   allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningObject, TaskCompletionSource 1 retry, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource 1 retry, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal&
>   connection)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
>   TaskCompletionSource 1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource 
>   1 retry)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource 1
>   retry)    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()    at
>   Tridion.ContentManager.Data.AdoNet.DatabaseUtilities.GetConnection()
>   at
>   Tridion.ContentManager.Data.AdoNet.DatabaseUtilities.ExecuteNonQuery(StoredProcedureInvocation
>   storedProcedureInvocation, FieldDictionary& dataFields)    at
>   Tridion.ContentManager.Data.AdoNet.DatabaseUtilities.ExecuteNonQuery(StoredProcedureInvocation
>   storedProcedureInvocation)    at
>   Tridion.ContentManager.Data.AdoNet.IdentifiableObjectDataMapper.Tridion.ContentManager.Data.IIdentifiableObjectDataMapper.IsExistingObject(TcmUri
>   id)    at Tridion.ContentManager.Session.IsExistingObject(String uri) 
>   at
>   Tridion.TranslationManager.DomainModel.CoreServiceProxy.CallWithErrorHandling[T](Func
>   1 callMethod, String traceFormatString, Object[] traceParameters)
>   at
>   Tridion.TranslationManager.DomainModel.TcmItemTranslationInfo.ResolveTcmUriForAppdataStorage(TcmUri
>   uri)    at
>   Tridion.TranslationManager.DomainModel.TcmItemTranslationInfo..ctor(TcmUri
>   itemUri, IDictionary 2 preloadedItems, IDictionary 2
>   preloadedAppDataDocuments, UserContext userContext)    at
>   Tridion.TranslationManager.DomainModel.Service.SendForTranslationTask.<>c__DisplayClass3c.b__39(<>f__AnonymousType32
>   2 <>h__TransparentIdentifier26)    at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.<>c__DisplayClass7_0`3.b__0(TSource
>   x)    at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator
>   2.MoveNext()    at Tridion.TranslationManager.DomainModel.Service.SendForTranslationTask.<>c__DisplayClass3c.b__28(TransactionScope
>   scope)    at
>   Tridion.TranslationManager.DomainModel.TmSession.<>c__DisplayClass66.b__65(TransactionScope
>   scope)    at
>   Tridion.TranslationManager.DomainModel.TmSession.ExecuteInTransactionScope[T](TransactionScopeOption
>   scopeOptions, TransactionOptions transactionOptions, Func 2 func)
>   at
>   Tridion.TranslationManager.DomainModel.TmSession.ExecuteInTransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption
>   scopeOptions, TransactionOptions transactionOptions, Action 1 action) 
>   at
>   Tridion.TranslationManager.DomainModel.TmSession.ExecuteInTransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption
>   scopeOptions, Action 1 action)    at
>   Tridion.TranslationManager.DomainModel.Service.SendForTranslationTask.FinalizeTmsJob(TranslationJob
>   job, TranslationSystemJobRequest jobRequest, IEnumerable 1
>   itemRequests)    at
>   Tridion.TranslationManager.DomainModel.Service.SendForTranslationTask.ProcessClient(TranslationJob
>   job, String clientId, List 1 resolvedItems)    at
>   Tridion.TranslationManager.DomainModel.Service.SendForTranslationTask.Process()
>   at
>   Tridion.TranslationManager.DomainModel.Service.ServiceTask.ThreadMethod()
>
> ---
>
> The partner transaction manager has disabled its support for
>   remote/network transactions. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8004D025)
>
> at
>   System.Transactions.Oletx.IDtcProxyShimFactory.ReceiveTransaction(UInt32
>   propgationTokenSize, Byte[] propgationToken, IntPtr managedIdentifier,
>   Guid& transactionIdentifier, OletxTransactionIsolationLevel&
>   isolationLevel, ITransactionShim& transactionShim)    at
>   System.Transactions.TransactionInterop.GetOletxTransactionFromTransmitterPropigationToken(Byte[]
>   propagationToken)

Is there an alternate configuration to avoid requiring MSDTC configuration with Translation Manager?

Answer (score 5):

You need to install the cm and tm databases into a single database - as far as i know, all you need to do is specify the same database name (and user I assume) when running the database install scripts.

Make sure the database information is 100% identical. For example, avoid using "(local)" for CM and "localhost" for TM. Casing does matter here.

Comment: I've updated my installation to point to the main content manager database (and deleted the separate Translation Manager database). However I still get the same error. I've updated the log to reflect the detailed error message

Comment: Usually this is mean that you have different connection strings in Tridion.ContentManager.config and TranslationManager.xml

Connection strings for CM and TM should be 100% identical. Character by character

Answer (score 4):

In addition to Lars' answer about having to install both the Translation Manager database (tables) and the Content Manager database (tables) into one database, you also need to make sure that both the CMS and Translation Manager are accessing the database with the same database credentials (username and password).

This was implied by Lars' suggestion to "Make sure the database information is 100% identical". However, I thought I'd make this extra clear as we had a similar problem using RDS recently.

Hope this helps!